# Is it possible to debug "Terminated due to memory error"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In a certain (consistent) point when my app is running, I consistently get the xcode error message

> Terminated due to memory error.

I cannot find the code causing the error, but I can tell what code is near the error (using breakpoints).

The error is caused directly after returning a certain cell in my implemenation of the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

`UITableViewDataSource` delegate method. I can confirm that it is returning a valid `UITableViewCell`, but I think that explaining and posting that entire method would be a waste of your time. However, I suspect it might be caused by a rapid, massive allocation of memory.

It definitely says `Terminated due to memory error`, not memory pressure.

I would like to know what is message really means. Also, is there any way to debug this message? No crash report is generated.

I am using **ARC** and iOS 7.

Comment: I saw the same error in Xcode. My app was crashing because I was creating a super-tall UIWebView (greater than 20000 pixels). I was never able to find a crash report, nor figure out a way to get memory warnings before the crash.

Comment: @HeathBorders I am using a UIWebview as well. That is very interesting. I will have to check the height on mine. Thanks!

Comment: This is kind of a common error with these components. The possible causes are: somehow you are generating too many cells (check your calculations), your cell sizes are wrong (as in dividing by 0 generating a nan which is kind of an infinite number when making the size). or incurring on an infinite loop.

Comment: @HeathBorders Now I am interested to know what device you were testing on?

Comment: I was testing on an iPad3. Also, my `UIWebView` wasn't just super-tall, it was also super-wide (30000px).

Comment: @HeathBorders This is very interesting. Everyone that participated in this post has been testing on iPad 3rd gen. Coincidence? Has anyone been able to reproduce the error on another device? I will try if I get a chance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482396/how-i-can-solve-terminated-due-to-memory-error

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711184/termination-due-to-memory-pressure-with-known-cause-unknown-solution

Comment: I am running with the same problem :|

Comment: same problem with iphone 6 +  for MKMapView. how can I solve it? it works fine in 4s

Comment: same error iPhone 6+

Comment: Same error in iPhone 6

Answer (score 60):

I was getting this error and could not understand what was wrong.

After some searching I found out that i forgot to disable zombies.

To disable do the following:

[image: Select edit scheme]

[image: Deselect "Enable Zombie Objects]

Comment: When zombies are enable everything is affected as objects are not deallocated. This fills up the memory very fast in the case of a table view where a lot of thing are being allocated and deallocated. Definition of Enable Zombies: Replace deallocated objects with a “zombie” object that traps any attempt to use it. When you send a message to a zombie object, the runtime logs an error and crashes. You can look at the backtrace to see the chain of calls that triggered the zombie detector.

Comment: Still, I'm facing the problem. Please guide me.

Comment: How do you disable zombies?

Answer (score 11):

**I was faced the same issue**.("Terminated due to Memory Error")
I had tried the above all answers but nothing work for me. Then i debug my code and found a for loop is running for infinity time with allocating memory to a array with nil value every time.its use 300+MB so it give this error

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly same issue. I thought it caused my program had memory leak or using too much memory. I use instruments and used allocating profile and program works fine. Also I ran program by device long enough, and it also works fine.

I also using iPad 3rd Gen for debugging, it might be causing because of that slow of the device or bug, it it seems like just Xcode and running from Xcode problem. Not the problem of memory leak or allocation.

If you make sure with instruments and running app on device itself and work

Comment: Hmmm. Everyone that participated in this post has been testing on iPad 3rd gen. Coincidence?

Comment: I only use iPad 3rd gen so I am not sure yet. Today I have ordered iPad mini retina, so I can provably answer this next week ;)

Comment: Just encountered this on an iPhone5S. Just added Google's tracking code and had to reduce from arm64 to arm7/7s as Google's slooooww at building arm64. I'd assumed this was an arm64/7s thing. Certainly not just an iPad 3rd gen issue. I had 'error in __connection_block_invoke_2' which separate searches tells me might be related to downloading too much and OOMing. Shame about the lack of stacktrace though....

Comment: I'm encountering it on an iPad mini 2nd-gen ([iPad4,4](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-mini-retina-2nd-gen-a1489-wi-fi-only-specs.html)).

Comment: I have similar issue when downloading whole bunch of images using NSURLSession. Simulator and standalone device(iPhone 6) works fine. In instruments, allocation diagram also looks smooth. Don't crash either. Problem occurs when I have device connected to xCode. No matter build configuration (Debug or Release). Always ends with mystery "Memory error".

Comment: I'm encountering it in iPhone6. Working fine on simulator but when i run my app in iPhone6 shows the memory error and also working fine in other devices like 5, 5S etc..

Comment: In my Universal app, I'm getting his problem with iPhone device 5s,6. But the same is working fine with iPad. So please suggest me for the same.

Answer (score 6):

I was using Tesseract for OCR and when my target text got scanned, a GIF was supposed to play. When the GIF started to play, there was a memory spike, from 70-80MB to 450MB. The problem was that GIF was taking too much memory, the app would crash and Xcode would show that message. So I removed the concerned imageView from the superview of the ViewController.

```
imageView.removeFromSuperview
```

After this, the app would still spike to 450MB but then immediately release and come down to 40MB

Comment: I spent 2 days to fix my memory crash, your solution helped. Thanks..!

Answer (score 5):

Restart device worked for me. “Terminated due to memory error” message stopped to appear.

Comment: This works for me. It's strange that the crash just appear out of the blue

Answer (score 3):

I got this error because I was adding full size photos to a collectionView cell sized 40x40. Read the [2 comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855711/image-in-collectionview-cell-causing-terminated-due-to-memory-issue/63860145#63860145) under the question from @matt. I had to [scale down the images](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36658996/4833705) before adding them to the cell.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I made a similar mistake, added splash images that were big. Make sure you make assets the correct size.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the scheme, under Diagnostics you'll find several options to guard allocations. [Refer to the documentation for details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html).

Question is: does it really say "terminated due to memory error" and not "pressure"? Check in instruments if your app is running low on memory, if the app does seem to run low on memory then that's what you should focus on regardless what the exact message is.

Comment: It definitely says "error" not "pressure". The memory level is consistently at about 15 MB at the time of crash.

Comment: Then try with malloc diagnostics enabled. Btw are you testing on a device?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in *Xcode 11.3* wherein ***camera was getting calling every-time we press on try again button.*** If these is done multiple times then crash happens.

This was **fixed when we disabled Zombie objects.** Below are steps:

1. Tap on project name present in top left. This will show list of targets present in project.
2. Tap on Edit scheme

[image: Screenshot-1]

3. Select Run option -> Diagnostics -> Uncheck Zombie Objects.

[image: Screenshot-2]

Now, run your project. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 11 it started my project in `Debug` mode. I am doing some image recording/editing/returning to the user and that is not something you can use in `Debug`. Once I turned to `Release` mode, all went well.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this kind of issue due to inattentiveness.

I've been calling a function, which adds imageView as subview in:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

This caused a huge memory usage, so be attentive to this sort of things!

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I noticed is that when I run my app on the device through cable and leave it idle for a long time I will also get that error.

[Apple do address this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpcconnection/1407915-interruptionhandler?language=objc) and it just might be that it feels like the app is idle and just kills it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a corrupted Image from the API which raised my memory from 100MB to 4.5 GB due to processing size it took to display on screen!

Answer (score 0):

An infinite `loop` was the cause of the `memory leak` for me. I could see the memory in `Xcode` rising to 1,6 `Gb` at which point the app crashed. The app's memory usage should be in `mb` and not `gb` and it should be relativly stable. If it rises quickly, say `100 mb` a second, there's definitely something wrong. If none of the suggestions above have worked, you should 1. check the memory usage of the app, and 2. if the usage is too high, look for loops you've recently added.