# Get "Terminated due to Memory error" for ios 8 custom keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

I am developing a ios 8 custom keyboard Extension. It run like a charm start.

But I always get "Receive Memory Warning" in Xcode. So my custom keyboard extension will suddenly terminate sometimes.

But I run the custom keyboard in its host app. There don't have any problem. Don't get "Receive Memory Warning" in Xcode. Don't terminate.

Anybody can help me? If app have any limit size for a Extension use?

[image: Terminated due to Memory Error]

Comment: I use https://github.com/Split82/iOSMemoryBudgetTest test my device (ipad 3 wifi). A app will crash when memory reach 600MB.

But my custom keyboard Extension only need almost 30M. iOS still give Memory Warning. There have any document about this problem?

Comment: I did more test. I add iOSMemoryBudgetTest into my custom keyboard. I got the custom keyboard extension will crush reach 40M!

Comment: I really don't know if it is only this problem in iOS beta 5. Or official release version will fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to debug "Terminated due to memory error"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203790/is-it-possible-to-debug-terminated-due-to-memory-error)

Comment: @SantaClaus, no. That topic discuss app not Extension

Comment: Try what it suggests. It should work the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Apple mentions in their [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html) that memory limits for app extensions are *significantly* lower than limits imposed on foreground apps. Additionally some types of extensions may have lower limits than others.

Apple is not explicit about these memory limits as far as I can tell and it's unclear if they are dependent on the device and how much memory other apps are consuming. But as Ethan mentioned, for keyboard extensions you should aim for less than 30MB to avoid crashing.

It's also important to test the extension when not running in Xcode or using a debug build configuration. It seems that the memory limits for debug builds are much higher.

Comment: Its annoying that Apple is being coy. Apple, Just tell us what the damn limit is!

Comment: what will you do if Apple give you the limite ? monitor your app memory usage and if it reach the X MB you will do something ? you already have the warning ..

Comment: You can see the actual limit in your Xcode. Attach debugger to your extension, run it, go to Debug Navigator > Memory and see the graf (plot). The limit appears there if you reach close to it. In my Call Directory extension, the limit is 12MB, which is great for my tens of thousands phone numbers. Thank you Apple very much.

Comment: Printscreen where you can see the memory limit: https://eway.cr/xcoderamlimit

Answer (score 3):

iOS allocates less memory to extensions as they are supposed to be light and do one thing well. I suppose shall try limit memory use under 30mb...

Comment: my today extension uses only 3mb, but still received this error, do you know why?

Comment: Same here man.... I believe issue with Debugger and not with the low memory. Hard time to debug extensions...