# iOS custom keyboard memory constraints

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension

Is there memory requirement set forth with custom keyboard extension? I recall reading somewhere that the keyboard can crash if you exceed a small amount of memory in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is 30MB, at which point you will receive one or two low memory events, and then your keyboard will be immediately killed and replaced with the system keyboard if you don't clean up the memory usage in a low memory handler.

The reasoning is that **application extensions**, which a custom keyboard is considered one of, are given very minimal RAM to play with.

Comment: Thanks - is this limit documented somewhere?

Comment: The only tidbit of documentation that refers to this at all that I can find is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html). I confirm the 30MB limit from experience on both iOS 8 and 9, as I'm working on keyboards as we speak.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354192/get-terminated-due-to-memory-error-for-ios-8-custom-keyboard-extension?rq=1) also refers to the 30MB limit.