# Unity3d 4.6.2 app runs fine on Ipad Air 2 iOS 8.1 but crashesh on Iphone 6 iOS 8.2

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Well the titel says it all the app runs fine on the Ipad but when I run it from  Xcode on the Iphone I simple get a app quit due to memory error. Any ideas ?

EDIT : Upgrading Unity to 4.6.3 fixed the issue.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203790/is-it-possible-to-debug-terminated-due-to-memory-error) Is a good question you might want to take a look at. It looks like it may be an issue with the scheme and allocation guarding. See LearnCocos2D's answer on the linked question.

Comment: @CalebB thanks for the response. Turns out Unity themselves had trouble with iOS 8.2 Upgrading unity to 4.6.3 fixed the issue.