# How to fix Terminated due to memory issue in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushviewcontroller

i moved one view controller to another view controller again i came back previous  screen,i am doing this job more than 10 time finally debugger showing "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue",app is crashed.
Communications error:  { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>

Comment: Instruments Memory Leaks, try to find what's your issue.

Comment: You have memory leak probably. Use "Instruments" profiler with "memory leak" template to check.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203790/is-it-possible-to-debug-terminated-due-to-memory-error

Comment: How are you moving to the next controller, and how are you moving back? It's impossible to answer this without more details.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                   {
                       ListViewMap *LVM=[[ListViewMap alloc] init];
                       [self.navigationController pushViewController:LVM
                                                            animated:YES];
                       
                   });

Comment: Try just, ListViewMap *LVM=[[ListViewMap alloc] init]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:LVM animated:YES];

Comment: Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue