# After enabling the Secure text entry for TextField App is crashing in building project form XCode 8

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode8

After start using XCode 8 I am facing this issue.

> getting Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue this
>   error after 20 seconds on log

Comment: Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203790/is-it-possible-to-debug-terminated-due-to-memory-error

Answer (score 1):

Remove all textfield from xib or storyboard remove all delegate of textfield and add textfield  newly.